# In Compiled Heist (Haskell), why must splices be created beforehand?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, heist

I can understand why HTML templates (.tpl files) must be processed beforehand (with `loadTemplates`) and put into the `HeistConfig`. This allow Heist to process the HTML into a more efficient format beforehand.

However, I don't understand why *splices* must also be created beforehand and put inside the `HeistConfig`. What is the benefit of this? I don't see the benefit because splices are computed at runtime anyway. What is the thought process behind this?

I think this may be because a splice can also execute code at *load-time* (in addition to runtime). Is this the primary explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice functions (compiled and interpreted) operate on nodes.  Think of splices as having a type signature of `Node -> m [Node]`.  This is a relatively expensive operation because it's operating at the DOM level.  The splice's result nodes get inserted back into the DOM tree, then the entire tree has to be rendered to a ByteString.  The idea behind compiled heist was to do as much of this rendering work as possible up front at application initialization time.  The output of the initialization would be `[Chunk]` where Chunk can either be a static ByteString or a dynamic `m ByteString` (actual types are slightly different).  Compiled splices have to be processed before the initialization converts the whole template from `[Node]` to `[Chunk]`.  And to maximize runtime efficiency that conversion happens at app initialization time.

For more information check out these links:

http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/compiled-splices

https://github.com/snapframework/heist/wiki/Compiled-Splice-Formulations

Comment: But if the computation (fetching from database, etc.) and its transformation into chunks  has to be done at run-time anyway, why do I have to create the splice at load-time? Why would that add efficiency?

Comment: I can understand why creating the splice at load-time would add efficiency if it does something significant at load time. But what about splices that do all their work at run-time? This is the point of my question.

Comment: @haskellHQ Reread your comments you have already said it yourself. In this way *some* splices can be optimized, while splices that *must* be run at runtime **cannot** be optimized in any case. Between optimizing what is possible to optimize and not optimizing anything what should the library designer choose?

Comment: @Bakuriu That's a good point. mightybyte: Can you confirm that Bakuriu's comments mirror the library designer's (your?) thought process? That would clear up everything.

Comment: I've added another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195348/passing-data-directly-into-templates-in-compiled-heist-haskell

Comment: @haskellHQ I think @Bakuriu is pretty much right.  The splice type is `Node -> m [Node]`, which is inherently slow.  It doesn't matter if your splice has an effective type of `m ByteString`.  Heist doesn't ever see that.  If you want simple string interpolation templates, you might bet better off with something like [mustache](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mustache).